# Content does not show in Coveo despite matching criteria

Tags: coveo

I have a Coveo search view I've customized to show content based on the page you're on matching to whether that value is in a multilist field in Sitecore. The server environment is on-prem CES 7 free version, using version 222 of the Coveo for Sitecore and associated API/CES/etc.

This is my query header:

```
aq:((@syssource==("Coveo_web_index") NOT @ftemplateid72783==("adb6ca4f-03ef-4f47-b9ac-9ce2ba53ff97","fe5dd826-48c6-436d-b87a-7c4210c7413b"))) (@fhaslayout72783 == "1" AND @fz95xpath72783 == "6377c5571646415ab4922f0f02830104" AND @falltemplates72783 == "9b610063e99f40b6afd5402f5cfaf2d2") (@fcommittees72783 == "1c631b4a5c0342f996d56bd7fb6ed81a")
cq:(@fz95xlanguage72783=="en" @fz95xlatestversion72783=="1")
```

This query returns no results. I went into the Coveo console and found one of the documents that's supposed to be in this result set, so I know it's in the specified index. The item has no security on it. I looked up the fields that are specified in the query:

```
@ftemplateid72783 - ca328a29-fbe3-41fc-afc0-​dbf8602823e8
@fhaslayout72783 - 1
@fz95xpath72783 - 11111111111111111111111111111111;​0de95ae441ab4d019eb067441b7c2450;​4c5e4cfbe30b446e917024609ce91722;​4a7bb7ee89fb4e02896bfb4e27d1ba57;​6377c5571646415ab4922f0f02830104;​777fdec3a8da45759797983b9f77f49c;​f7e17f6a646d4bc68b6a4f1abb3fdb0c;​8e30e4b87e2b405eb7d53922c6c9318d
@falltemplates72783 - ca328a29fbe341fcafc0dbf8602823e8;​9b610063e99f40b6afd5402f5cfaf2d2
@fcommittees72783 - 897ad68518d1427c81d5070dfef1869a;​1c631b4a5c0342f996d56bd7fb6ed81a
@fz95xlanguage72783 - en
@fz95xlatestversion72783 - 1
```

So it looks like the content matches the criteria, which leaves me perplexed as to why it's not working right. The folks using the system have said if only one item is selected in the list, it appears to work fine, so is there a different syntax in the `buildingQuery` statement that I need other than `args.queryBuilder.advancedExpression.add('@Model.ToCoveoFieldName("Committees") == "' + pageId + '"');`? I was going with that because it worked for the path and "all templates" parameters.

Comment: Is your `fcommittees72783` a multi-value field? A computed field? If the field is free-text searchable, it will be expanded in the searchbox, but not in the `aq` part of the query. Also, have you tried this query directly in CES?

Comment: The field is a multilist in Sitecore...I'm not sure if there's anything extra I need to do with that to make it work right? Maybe this is the article I need to reference? https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV4/Making+a+Sitecore+Field+Multi-Value;jsessionid=51D96B0374148ADD5DD75711CB59047B

Comment: You could check the fields configuration in the CES Admin Tool. That will let you know if it is already multi-value.

Comment: It's String, not multi-value, just like all templates and path, according to the field list in the item I looked up. That's from the Content browser that I see that.

Comment: `alltemplates` and `_path` are defined in the `Coveo.SearchProvider.config` fieldMap as multi-value using the `isMultiValue="true"`parameter. You should probably define `committees` as multi-value there also.

Comment: I'll do that and check back in. Thanks @flguillemette!

Comment: That worked...if you want to file an answer I'll give you the credit. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@fcommittees72783` should be a multi-value field because it contains values separated by semicolons (`897ad68518d1427c81d5070dfef1869a;​1c631b4a5c0342f996d56bd7fb6ed81a`)

If a field with semicolons is not multi-value, the index will take that field as a standard string field, not returning results when the document matches only one of those values.

To set this flag, get in the `Coveo.SearchProvider.Custom.config` and add the following line in the `defaultIndexConfiguration` node:

```
<fieldMap type="Coveo.SearchProvider.CoveoFieldMap, Coveo.SearchProvider">
  <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
      <fieldType fieldName="committees" isMultiValue="true" settingType="Coveo.Framework.Configuration.FieldConfiguration, Coveo.Framework" />
  </fieldNames>
</fieldMap>
```

(You can also add it directly in your `Coveo.SearchProvider.Config`, but it might get overwritten when updating)

Also, your other fields `fz95xpath72783` and `falltemplates72783` are already defined as multi-value fields in the fieldMap OOTB.

Comment: This worked perfectly - I set all my multilist and checkboxlist fields as isMultiValue and got the results in Coveo I was expecting. Thanks!